# Sharing ownership over a dynamic array

Tags: c++

I have a container class which receives a pointer to a dynamic array from a c api. This class then becomes the owner of the buffer and must delete it using delete[].

So this buffer might have been created as follows:

Value*ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof(Value));

I also have a class called ValueWrapper which operates on a single Value.

My container has a getter which returns ValueWrapper objects, something like this:

```
ValueWrapper Container::valueWrapper(int index)
{
    return ValueWrapper(_value[index]);
}
```

However, objects of type VWrapper will have an invalid Value* once my container is destroyed.

How can I deal with this problem? I need to share ownership of Value*'s in some way. Would it be reasonable to insist that ValueWrapper objects can only be used when the Container is in scope and write this in the comment for Container::valueWrapper(int index)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want shared ownership, then you can unpack the array into an array of [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and remove the deletions. If you don't have C++11 support you could use `boost::shared_ptr` or `std::tr1::shared_ptr`.

Comment: For simpler usage, `std::shared_ptr` with the right deallocator can manage the array as a whole.

Comment: @juanchopanza Does that mean that I create a std::vector<std::shared_ptr> and push_back std::shared_ptr objects initialized with Value*'s from each location within the buffer.

Comment: @Baz that would be one way to do it, but you don't have to push_back. You can use the vector's two iterator constructor.