# std::vector of std::shared_ptr usage

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

The following code:

```
class Something
{
public:
     ~Something()
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    Something* s = new Something[1]; // raw pointer received from C api
    std::shared_ptr<Something> p = std::shared_ptr<Something>(s);
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Something>> v(&p,&p+1);

    return 0;
}
```

gives the following error in VS Express 2010:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual C++ Debug Library
---------------------------
Debug Assertion Failed!

File: f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgdel.cpp
Line: 52

Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
```

Remove the destructor from Something and the error disappears, Why do I get this error?

**Update:**

Later I will have something like:

```
Something* s = new Something[100];
```

and individual shared pointers will be passed around to other objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Something* s = new Something[1]; // raw pointer received from C api
std::shared_ptr<Something> p = std::shared_ptr<Something>(s);
```

is incorrect usage, since

```
~shared_ptr();
```

> Effects:
> — If *this is empty or shares ownership with another shared_ptr instance (use_count() > 1),
> there are no side effects.
>
> — Otherwise, if *this owns an object p and a deleter d, d(p) is called.
>
> — Otherwise, *this owns a pointer p, and delete p is called.

Default deleter is `operator delete`, but you have `Something* s = new Something[1];` allocated by array-new operator, that should be deleted with array-delete operator (delete[]), otherwise it's undefined behaviour. You should construct shared_ptr with specific deleter, or use something for arrays, for example `boost::shared_array`.

For example this code is correct.

```
template<typename T>
void deleter(T* p)
{
   delete[] p;
}

Something* s = new Something[1]; // raw pointer received from C api
std::shared_ptr<Something> p = std::shared_ptr<Something>(s, deleter<Something>);
```

Comment: I was thinking in terms of:  Something* s = new Something[2]; delete s; delete (s+1); With each shared pointer in the vector calling delete (s+n). But that isn't valid of course. How might the deleter look? s in my original post might point to a large array, not an array of just 1.

Comment: With regard to the deleter, should I go through the vector and check the use count and call delete[] when it hits zero?

Comment: @Baz no, vector destructor calls automatically and calls destructors of objects, that contains.

Comment: @Baz I don't think this will do what you need. It seems to me that this makes a shared_ptr out of the whole array, not individual elements.

Comment: How would the deleter look in this case: Something* s = new Something[2]; std::shared_ptr<Something> p1 = std::shared_ptr<Something>(s, deleter); std::shared_ptr<Something> p1 = std::shared_ptr<Something>(s+1, deleter);

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a C array full of dynamically allocated pointers, the usage of the vector of shared_ptr is greatly simplified:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct Foo { };

int main() {

  Foo* foos[5]; // simulate the array of pointers from C API
  foos[0] = new Foo();
  foos[1] = new Foo();
  foos[2] = new Foo();
  foos[3] = new Foo();
  foos[4] = new Foo();

  // create vector of shared_ptrs to C pointers
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> v(foos, foos+5);

}
```

Comment: No, I actually get a pointer to the first item in a dynamically allocated array. For example an array of 100 Somethings: Something* s = new Something[100];

Comment: Please see this question to understand my original problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982901/sharing-ownership-over-a-dynamic-array